# php cron with blank space in filename problem

Tags: php, cron

`if(file_exists("news/Main News.xml"))` returns `FALSE` when run through cron, but returns `TRUE` while run from browser.

Is it happening because of white space in filename but it is running ok with browser run.

Comment: what about "news/Main\ News.xml" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely this is caused by the cron job not being run from the correct folder.

You either need to do something like

```
    if(file_exists("/home/path/to/news/Main News.xml"))
```

(with the full path in the quotes)

or do a

```
    cd /home/path/to;php cron_file.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling the php from within the cronjob, call a shell script which is calling the php file then.

You can then change the environment the script is running in w/o the need to change the cronjob and you can easier test-drive the cron command (as you can just call the shell-script).

You can then, in the shell script, change the directory where the php-script expects to be in which will most certainly solve your issue.